# how to move the buttons on the navbar to the right edge of the page

Tags: button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa3Nr.png)

I want to move the bottons on the navbar to the right edge of the page. So I used the class " navbar-right" but the buttons stay at the center. what can i do?
here is what i wrote.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse"> 
  <div class="container-flulid">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-left ">
      <a style="font-family:Serif;font-size:50px" class="navbar-brand" href="#">KHS</a>
    </div> 
    <div id="barbuttons" class="navbar-right  navbar-btn" >
<button style="width:150px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">Home</button>
<button style="width:150px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary " >Portofolio</button>
<button style="width:150px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">Contact</button>
   </div>   
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navbar-right` should do the trick.
You better investigate with browser dev tools.

For Chrome, hit **F12** and select **Elements** then using the **select elements tool** (top left button), inspect the element styles.
More info: [Inspect and Edit Pages and Styles](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/)

Explorer is similar; hit **F12** and select **DOM Explorer** then using the **select elements tool** (top left button), inspect the element styles.
More info: [Diagnose and fix layout problems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255008(v=vs.85).aspx)

Other browsers have similar features.

Comment: I'm writing this code on Codepen. I selected Bootstrap 3 instead of Bootstrap4 then i worked. What's the differene between them?

Comment: There are some big changes in class naming conventions and much more. Apparently _ml-auto_ should right align your nav in bootstrap 4